# How to parse nested JSON array to dataset?

Tags: c#, json

```
"Data": [
    {
       "Code": "DEMO",
       "Name": "DEMO",
       "UserId": "B27A68AD-7C21-4DDB-8A1D-8932459CF53B",
       "RoleDetails": [{
            "ViewId": "B27A68AD-7C21-4DDB-8A1D-8932459CF53B",
            "IsAddAllowed": true,
            "IsEditAllowed": true,
            "IsDeleteAllowed": true
        }],
        "RoleDetails1":[ {
            "ViewId": "B27A68AD-7C21-4DDB-8A1D-8932459CF53B",
            "IsAddAllowed": true,
            "IsEditAllowed": true,
            "IsDeleteAllowed": true
          }]

    }
]
```

I have this JSON Array I want to convert this to `DataSet` having `DataTable` for Each Property in JSON.

Comment: Did you try anything, or just ask the question first?

Comment: `RoleDetails` and `RoleDetails1` are two seperate properties or `List<Role>`?

Comment: They are two different properties

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange @Kunalsingh.  Please read the '[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' article.  It's a good place to start here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one easy way to convert JSON to Dataset using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library

```
string json = @"{
""Data"": [
{
""Code"": ""DEMO"",
""Name"": ""DEMO"",
""UserId"": ""B27A68AD-7C21-4DDB-8A1D-8932459CF53B"",
""RoleDetails"": [{
""ViewId"": ""B27A68AD-7C21-4DDB-8A1D-8932459CF53B"",
""IsAddAllowed"": true,
""IsEditAllowed"": true,
""IsDeleteAllowed"": true
}],
""RoleDetails1"":[ {
""ViewId"": ""Z27A68AD-7C21-4DDB-8A1D-8932459CF53B"",
""IsAddAllowed"": true,
""IsEditAllowed"": true,
""IsDeleteAllowed"": true
}]
}
]
}";

var dt1 = ChoJSONReader.DeserializeText(json, "$.Data[0].RoleDetails").AsDataTable();
var dt2 = ChoJSONReader.DeserializeText(json, "$.Data[0].RoleDetails1").AsDataTable();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
```

Hope it helps.